# How to add table to "Favorites" in phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have phpMyAdmin ver 4.8.5. How do I add tables to "Favorites"? When I search for it in the documentation, it returns a [french entry](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/search.html?q=favorites&check_keywords=yes&area=default), which I don't understand.

[image: How to add favorite tables]

Comment: Took me 10 years to see this field, same for "Recent".

Comment: 13 years for me haha.

Answer (score 16):

The French entry is totally unrelated and have nothing to do with your question.

To add a table as favorite, you just have to click on the star next to his name.

[image: table]

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to figure it our for more than an hour.

Comment: That is: select the database first to view the table list with stars. There are no stars in the navigation panel.

Comment: This feature clearly needs more visibility.
Using it to bookmark some performance schema tables, like USER_STATISTICS from mariadb plugin to monitor load.